# Iptables DNAT with multiple interface

Tags: iptables

I have 2 Machines:

```
MachineDev
ens5: 10.41.12.63 (the default net device)
ens8: 10.41.10.111
```

```
 MachineProxy
ens5: 10.40.9.106 (the default net device)
ens6: 10.40.2.114
```

And I want use `MachineProxy` as proxy to establish a tcp between `MachineDev` and some ip like `3.117.113.6:443`(just a example).

Here is what I set the iptables on `MachineProxy`

```
sudo iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 8250 -j DNAT --to 3.117.113.6:443
sudo iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 3.117.113.6 --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -t filter -j ACCEPT
```

(these rules are at the top of the chain, so they will be match first)

The problem: I can use the DNAT proxy with `MachinDev ens5` and `MachineProxy ens5 8250`, everything works fine. But I can't establish a simple tcp connection with `MachinDev ens8` and `MachineProxy ens6 8250`. Why and How?

`MachinDev ens5` and `MachineProxy ens5` are in an AWS-subnet, `MachinDev ens8` and `MachineProxy ens6` are in another AWS-subnet.

Here is some logs I tried to solve it, Firstly I add a rule:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -i ens6 -p tcp -m tcp -s 10.41.10.111/20  -j TRACE
```

and then that's all the log in sys:

```
Aug  2 12:03:06 ip-10-40-9-106 kernel: [ 4750.945947] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens6 OUT= MAC=06:35:e3:6c:6d:b9:06:b5:d6:be:37:d1:08:00 SRC=10.41.10.111 DST=10.40.2.114 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57725 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37888 DPT=8250 SEQ=3375071032 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A395228250000000001030307)
Aug  2 12:03:06 ip-10-40-9-106 kernel: [ 4750.945975] TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:rule:2 IN=ens6 OUT= MAC=06:35:e3:6c:6d:b9:06:b5:d6:be:37:d1:08:00 SRC=10.41.10.111 DST=10.40.2.114 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57725 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37888 DPT=8250 SEQ=3375071032 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A395228250000000001030307)
Aug  2 12:03:06 ip-10-40-9-106 kernel: [ 4750.945984] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens6 OUT=ens5 MAC=06:35:e3:6c:6d:b9:06:b5:d6:be:37:d1:08:00 SRC=10.41.10.111 DST=3.117.113.6 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=57725 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37888 DPT=443 SEQ=3375071032 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A395228250000000001030307)
Aug  2 12:03:06 ip-10-40-9-106 kernel: [ 4750.945991] TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:rule:2 IN=ens6 OUT=ens5 MAC=06:35:e3:6c:6d:b9:06:b5:d6:be:37:d1:08:00 SRC=10.41.10.111 DST=3.117.113.6 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=57725 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37888 DPT=443 SEQ=3375071032 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A395228250000000001030307)
Aug  2 12:03:07 ip-10-40-9-106 kernel: [ 4751.975233] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens6 OUT= MAC=06:35:e3:6c:6d:b9:06:b5:d6:be:37:d1:08:00 SRC=10.41.10.111 DST=10.40.2.114 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57726 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37888 DPT=8250 SEQ=3375071032 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A39522C2A0000000001030307)
Aug  2 12:03:07 ip-10-40-9-106 kernel: [ 4751.975253] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens6 OUT=ens5 MAC=06:35:e3:6c:6d:b9:06:b5:d6:be:37:d1:08:00 SRC=10.41.10.111 DST=3.117.113.6 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=57726 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37888 DPT=443 SEQ=3375071032 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A39522C2A0000000001030307)
```